# Update Column name with default values if value doen't exist in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have added a module in rails concern to update two attributes with a default value.

But not able to do it. Could someone please explain it?

```rb
module DefaultValueForCreateAndUpdateUserid
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    before_save do
      self.create_uid = 'x' if !self.create_uid?
      self.last_updt_uid = 'x' if !self.last_updt_uid?
    end
  end
end
```

But it is giving this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `before_save' for DummyValueForCreateAndUpdateUserid:Module
```

Comment: May be it's better to have `DEFAULT` constraint on these columns in DB layer. In this case you don't need this callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`included`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included) and also `||=` to check and assign attribute

```
module DefaultValueForCreateAndUpdateUserid
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :assign_absent_attributes
  end

  def assign_absent_attributes
    self.create_userid ||= 'f'
    self.last_updt_userid ||= 'f'
  end
end
```

And than include this concern in the model

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  include DefaultValueForCreateAndUpdateUserid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fit your needs.

```rb
module DefaultValueForCreateAndUpdateUserid
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern


  included do
    before_save do
      self.create_userid = 'f' if !self.create_userid?
      self.last_updt_userid = 'f' if !self.last_updt_userid?
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  include DefaultValueForCreateAndUpdateUserid
end
```